# Split a string after second occurrence of character onwards

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string suppose `/index/something/something` .I want to split such that ,I get `["/index","something","something"]`

I have tried the below code ,but its not what actually I am looking .I am looking for some regex which just skip first `/` and then split by second onwards.

```
let url="/index/something";
console.log(url.split(/(?<=.{6})/))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `.match` instead, and optionally match the beginning of the string followed by `/`, followed by non-`/` characters:

```js
let url="/index/something";
console.log(
  url.match(/(?:^\/)?[^/]+/g)
);
```

- `(?:^\/)?` - Optionally match the beginning of the string followed by `/`
- `[^/]+` - Match one or more non-`/` characters

Comment: Can you please elaborate this regex a bit?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this one.

```
let url="/index/something";
console.log(
  url.match(/[^/]+/g)
);
```